# Access token obtained with 'auth-code' login flow with 'drive.file' scope, later used for picking file and on the server returns "entity not found"

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, google-picker

I need help.

I use 'auth-code' login flow (with 'drive.file' scope) in my react app, and then exchange this cde on the server for access and refresh token, and return access_token back to react frontend.
Then i create picker object and inject access_token using

```
   .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
```

and Picker opens file and lets me pick file (this file was not created by my app, but just selected by the user) After this on the backend I try to read the content of this file and getting:

```
googleapi: Error 404: Requested entity was not found
```

Don't know what to do. Should I try server side flow for oauth? From my understand of the docs, what I did must've worked. Please help.

tried obtaining access token using frontend flow and pasting it to the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, think I figured it out... Solution below with my original comment below that.

**Solution**

The solution is hinted at in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119557/getting-google-file-picker-to-work-with-drive-file-scope]. The fix is to add the following to the `PickerBuilder`:

```js
.setAppId(DriveApiKey)
```

Where `DriveApiKey` is the first part of the associated oAuth client ID. So if the client ID is `123456789-abc123xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com` then the ApiKey is just `123456789-abc123xyz`. Not sure why that is but seems to work.

**Original Post**

I've been running into the same problem, no solutions so far but here are a few more details on what I'm trying unsuccessfully. Would be interested to know what commonalities/differences you have.

My setup:

- Next.js app
- User management via Clerk
- GoogleFilePicker to choose a file on the client (Google Spreadsheets only)
- Client call to spreadsheet API to get the list of tabs/sheets, using the fileId from above

Flow:

- User logs in to my app using Clerk and they store the oauth tokens.
- User selects "Open GSheet" from my app.
- My app calls Clerk to get an access token.
- That token is then used to show the file picker.
- User picks a file.
- My app calls the Google spreadsheet API using the same access token and the fileId chosen.

The last step results in a 404.

I've tried using a readonly scope, which works but is more than I need.

I've had success periodically but I can't track it down to any series of reproducable steps.